# Nodemailer doesn't seem to be freeing up TCP Ports after a mail has been sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, rabbitmq, nodemailer

As the question says, I'm having an issue with our bulk mailing server.
So for abit of background, This emailing application of ours runs on a CRON job, sending out mails every hour.
Every 12 hours, We send out our biggest bulks, there are around 8 different groups and each group can have anywhere between 2000 - 4000 mails in each group that needs to be sent.

This application is built in Nodejs and uses Nodemailer to handle the sending of the mails.

What I've noticed for awhile now is that every so often the server would essentially "freeze" up and the memory usage of the app would slowly climb.

Windows Event log showed this error after the last bulk emailing was meant to run, "A request to allocate an ephemeral port number from the global TCP port space has failed due to all such ports being in use."

I've gone through the [documentation](https://nodemailer.com/usage/bulk-mail/) on the Nodemailer website and applied the following changes

1. Using a pooled SMTP - This is still currently in the application
2. Set maxMessages to infinity - I've removed this as it didn't seem to help
3. Set maxConnections to 20 - Also removed because it made no difference
4. Using a dedicated queue manager - This was my final attempt, I went with RabbitMQ and have applied their Publish/Subscribe model.

RabbitMQ has improved the performance alot but it still hasn't resolved the issue.

Publish Function

```
const PublishMails = (mailObj) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var publishMailResult = {};

        if (mailObj.length > 0) {
            var connection = global.RabbitMQConnection;
            connection.createChannel((err, channel) => {
                if (err) {
                    publishMailResult.Result = false;
                    publishMailResult.Message = err.stack;
                    resolve(publishMailResult);
                    //return process.exit(1);
                }

                channel.assertQueue(config.RabbitMQ.Queue_EmailQueue, {
                    durable: true
                }, err => {
                    if (err) {
                        publishMailResult.Result = false;
                        publishMailResult.Message = err.stack;
                        resolve(publishMailResult);
                        //return process.exit(1);
                    }

                    var mailData = {}

                    for (var x = 0; x < mailObj.length; x++) {
                        mailData.from = 'XXX@XXX.com';
                        mailData.to = mailObj[x].Email;
                        mailData.firstName = mailObj[x].FirstName;
                        mailData.login = mailObj[x].Login;
                        mailData.email = mailObj[x].Email;
                        mailData.mailID = mailObj[x].MailID;
                        mailData.sendID = mailObj[x].SendID;
                        mailData.subject = "Email Message";
                        mailData.template = 'EmailTempLate';

                        channel.sendToQueue(config.RabbitMQ.Queue_EmailQueue, 
                       Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(mailData)), {
                            persistent: true,
                            contentType: 'application/json'
                        });

                        if (x === mailObj.length - 1) {
                            channel.close();
                            publishMailResult.Result = true;
                            publishMailResult.Message = "All mails successfully published.";
                            resolve(publishMailResult);
                        }
                    }
                });
            })
        } else {
            publishMailResult.Result = false;
            publishMailResult.Message = "No mails were received - Mails Not Published.";
            resolve(publishMailResult);
        }

    });
}
```

Subscribe function

```
const SubscribeMails = (mailObj) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (mailObj.PublishMailResult.Result == true) {
            var options = {
                viewEngine: {
                    extname: '.html',
                    layoutsDir: 'views/email/',
                    defaultLayout: 'Email_Template'
                },
                viewPath: 'views/email',
                extName: '.html'
            };

            var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
                host: 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XX',
                port: 25,
                pool: true
            }));

            transporter.use('stream', require('nodemailer-dkim').signer({
                domainName: 'XXX.com',
                keySelector: 'main',
                privateKey: 'XXXX'
            }));

            transporter.use('compile', hbs(options));

            var connection = global.RabbitMQConnection;
            connection.createChannel((err, channel) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err.stack);
                    return process.exit(1);
                }

                channel.assertQueue(config.RabbitMQ.Queue_EmailQueue, {
                    durable: true
                }, err => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err.stack);
                        return process.exit(1);
                    }

                    channel.prefetch(1);

                    channel.consume(config.RabbitMQ.Queue_EmailQueue, data => {

                        if (data === null) {
                            return;
                        }

                        let mail = JSON.parse(data.content.toString());
                        transporter.sendMail({
                            from: mail.from,
                            to: mail.to,
                            subject: mail.subject,
                            template: mail.template,
                            context: {
                                FirstName: mail.firstName,
                                Email: mail.email,
                                MailID: mail.mailID,
                                SendID: mail.sendID,
                            }
                        }, (err, info) => {
                            if (err) {
                                console.error(err.stack);
                                return channel.nack(data);
                            }

                            channel.ack(data);

                            channel.checkQueue(config.RabbitMQ.Queue_EmailQueue, function (checkErr, queueData) {
                                if (queueData != null) {
                                    if (queueData.messageCount == 0) {
                                        channel.close();
transporter.close(); // Added in to test if this free's up TCP ports - Didn't help
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });

                    resolve(true);
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

It really feels like I'm meant to be somehow closing these TCP connections manually but I haven't seen anything written about this in the documentation or haven't seen it mentioned on any example code I've seen.

I'm adding in the Cron job that starts this process to perhaps help debug this issue.

```
var cronPCSec = '0';
var cronPCMin = '58';
var cronPCHour = '*';
var cronPCDay = '*';
var cronPCMonth = '*';
var cronPCDayOfWeek = '0-6';
var cronPCfulltimes = "" + cronPCSec + " " + cronPCMin + " " + cronPCHour + " " + cronPCDay + " " + cronPCMonth + " " + cronPCDayOfWeek + "";


var MailerCronJob = new CronJob({
    cronTime: cronPCfulltimes,
    onTick: function () {
        let objCronJob = {};

        modelPC.GetMails().then(function (mail) {
            return mail;
        }).then(PublishMails).then(function (PublishResult) {
            objCronJob.PublishMailResult = PublishResult;
            return objCronJob;
        }).then(SubscribeMails).then(function (result) {
            console.log("Completed Successfully");
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("Failed");
            console.log(err)
        });
    },
    start: false
});

MailerCronJob.start();
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you certain it's tcp connections from the mailer that are staying open? According to the NodeMailer docs it will at most open 5 connections per pool unless you're overriding those numbers, and it doesn't seem like you do.

Comment: Hi @Evert, Thanks for your response. Yes I am certain it's from the Mailer. When I log onto our mailing server, I can see everything is 'frozen' up only after I restart the nodemailer server, the system resources are freed and everything starts running as it should.